# How do I get a span over an image map

Tags: jquery, html

I see others have the same question, but nothing I tried worked. I'm hoping someone can just update this code so it shows the 123 over the image when you click on the image.

https://jsfiddle.net/tgbvf3sy/2/

```
<html>  
  <head>  
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>Image Test</title>  
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>  
    <script>  
      $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("#test").click(function(){
          $("#test").append('span').text('123');
        });
      });   
    </script>  
  </head>  
  <body>
    <div>
      <img id="ohiomap" src="http://www.echoecho.com/rainbow.gif" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
      <map name="Map" id="Map">
        <area shape="rectangle" coords="0,10,20,30" id="test"/>
      </map>
    </div>
  </body>  
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: The coords should be 0,0,50,50

Comment: Also, this does not work in Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. Firstly your use of `.append('span').text('123')` is appending text values in both cases. To add a `span` use HTML within the `append()` call. You also need to append the `span` to the containing `div`, not the `map` as that will just result in invalid HTML.

To align the appended `span` centrally you just need to use CSS positioning, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test").click(function() {
    $("#container").append('<span>123</span>');
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}
#container span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  left: 0;
  width: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <img id="ohiomap" src="http://www.echoecho.com/rainbow.gif" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
  <map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area shape="rectangle" coords="0,0,50,50" id="test" />
  </map>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/tgbvf3sy/9/

You can then play around with `left` and `top` to position exactly as you want.

Comment: Thank you exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad i could help :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/tgbvf3sy/10/](https://jsfiddle.net/tgbvf3sy/10/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
        $("#test").click(function(){
            $("#test").append('<span>123</span>');
    });
}); 

#test span
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 29px;
    left: 24px;
    color: red;
}
```